# Copy to clipboard with label and content

Tags: javascript, html

How to copy to clipboard code but not just copy i need the label included?

Like example:

```
SESA461290

Name Shin Abbas 

Callback +639087614***
```

I'm a newbie and this is the first time i'm doing this

```html
<head>
  <title>Shin's Call Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form-style-2">
    <form action="" method="get">
      <div class="form-style-2-heading">Shin's Template

        <label for="INtemp"><select name="INtemp" id="INtemp" class="temp-options">
        <option value="" style="display:none">Menu</option>
        <option value="1">ADP password reset</option>
        <option value="20">Autotime password reset</option>
        <option value="2">AMAPS password reset</option>
        <option value="3">Lotus Notes Password reset</option>
        <option value="4">Q2C/EQM password reset</option>
        <option value="5">SAP password reset</option>
        <option value="17">Windows password reset</option>
        <option value="6" class="INql" disabled>---Common Issues----</option>
        <option value="7">Box device security issue</option>
        <option value="19">Inquiry Call</option>
        <option value="8">Laptop Issue</option>
        <option value="9">Network drive issue</option>
        <option value="16">Outlook conenctivity issue</option>
        <option value="18">Misrouted</option>
        <option value="10">PING ID unpairing device</option>
        <option value="11">Pulse secure (unable to login)</option>
        <option value="12">Pulse secure installation</option>
        <option value="13">Unable to login on Windows</option>
        <option value="14">Windows locked out</option>
        <option value="15">Windows trust relatinship issue</option>
          </select></label>
      </div>

      &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
      <label><input class="INNewExec" onclick="openNew();" type="button" value="New" /></label>
      <!-- New Button -->
      <label><span>&nbsp</span><input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetPage();" /></label>
      <!-- Reset Button -->
      <label><span>&nbsp</span><input type="submit" onclick="return false;" class="INSubmitExec" value="Submit" /></label>
      <!-- Submit Button -->

      <br>
      <br>
      <!-- below codes are for the LOB radio buttons Dist(distributor) SE (SE employee) Ext (External)-->
      <label><span>Clients</span>
  <input type="radio" name="INlob" id="checkboxDist" value="Dist-client" class="input-radio" /> 
    <label for="checkboxDist" class="checkbox-label-Dist">Distributor</label>
      <b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp|&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</b>
      <input type="radio" name="INlob" id="checkboxSE" value="SE-LOB" class="input-radio" />
      <label for="checkboxSE" class="checkbox-label-SE">SE</label>
      <b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp|&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</b>
      <input type="radio" name="INlob" id="checkboxExt" value="Ext" class="input-radio" />
      <label for="checkboxExt" class="checkbox-label-Ext">External</label>

      <!-- below codes are for the Severity radio buttons -->
      <br>
      <br>
      <label><span>Severity</span>
  <input onClick="showMIM(1)" type="radio" name="INsev" id="radioCrit" value="Critical P1" class="input-radio" /> <label for="radioCrit" class="radio-label-Crit">Critical- P1</label>
      <input onClick="showMIM(0)" type="radio" name="INsev" id="radioHigh" value="High P2" class="input-radio" /> <label for="radioHigh" class="radio-label-High">High-P2</label>
      <input onClick="showMIM(0)" type="radio" name="INsev" id="radiomed" value="Medium P3" class="input-radio" /> <label for="radioMed" id="radio-label-Med3" class="radio-label-Med">Medium-P3</label></label>

      <br><br><br><br><br>
      <label for="INname"><span>SESA</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="INname" value="" id="INname"size="40" /></label><label><input type="checkbox" name="INvip" id="INvip" value="VIP" class="input-checkbox"><b>VIP</b></label>
      <!-- VIP checkbox -->
      <br>
      <label for="INempid"><span>NAME</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="INempid" id="INempNam" value="" size="40" /></label>
      <br>
      <label for="INloc"><span>CALLBACK</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="INloc" value="" id="INCall" size="40" /></label>
      <br>
      <label for="INclient"><span>EMAIL</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="INclient" id="IN" value="" size="40" /></label>
      <br>
      <label for="INphone"><span>Phone Number</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="INphone" id="INphone" value="" size="40" /></label>
      <br>
      <label for="INemail"><span>RELATED#</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="INemail" value="" id="INemail" size="40" /></label>
      <br>
      <label for="INbrief"><span>LOCATION</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="INbrief" id="INbrief" value="" size="40" /></label>

      <br>
      <br>
      <label for="INbrief"><span>Application name:</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="INbrief" id="INbrief" value="" size="40" /></label>
      <br>
      <label for="INbrief"><span>No.of Affected Users</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="INbrief" id="INbrief" value="" size="40" /></label>
      <br>
      <br>
      <label for="INempid"><span style="width:100px; text-align:LEFT;">What is the problem?</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="INempid" id="INempid" value="" size="40" /></label>
      <br>
      <label for="INloc"><span style="width:100px; text-align:LEFT;">When did the issue begin?</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="INloc" value="" id="INloc" size="40" /></label>
      <br>
      <label for="INclient"><span style="width:140" /></label>
      <br>
      <label for="INphone"><span style="width:100px; text-align:LEFT;">Error message</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="INphone" id="INphone" value="" size="40" /></label>
      <br>
      <label for="INemail"><span style="width:100px; text-align:LEFT;">Last time it worked properly</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="INemail" value="" id="INemail" size="40" /></label>
      <br>
      <label for="INbrief"><span style="width:100px; text-align:LEFT;">any changes to your PC since the last time it worked properly</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="INbrief" id="INbrief" value="" size="40" /></label>
      <br>
      <label for="INbrief"><span style="width:100px; text-align:LEFT;">Have you changed your password recently:</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="INbrief" id="INbrief" value="" size="40" /></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this similar question:
 ["How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript).
*This page has many answers explaining how to copy text to your clipboard using both JavaScript and text-areas.*

## Best methods for your issue:

#### **Method 1:** This method uses an HTML text-area and button connected to an [Event Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/addeventlistener/info) ([addeventlistener](/questions/tagged/addeventlistener)). ***This is most likely the best choice for you.***

***Source*** ​ - ​  ​ **From:** [Dean Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/406712/dean-taylor) ​ ​ **Original:** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/8589728)

```js
var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.js-textareacopybtn');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.js-copytextarea');
  copyTextarea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
});
```

```html
<p>
  <button class="js-textareacopybtn" style="vertical-align:top;">Copy Textarea</button>
  <textarea class="js-copytextarea">Hello I'm some text</textarea>
</p>
```

### **Method 2:** This method uses a function as apposed to an HTML text area and button.

***Source*** ​ - ​  ​ **From:** [Bart Burg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1274398/bart-burg) ​ ​ **Original:** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31320370/8589728)

```
var copyToClipboard = function(textToCopy){
    $("body")
        .append($('<input type="text" name="fname" class="textToCopyInput"/>' )
        .val(textToCopy))
        .find(".textToCopyInput")
        .select();
      try {
        var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
        var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
        alert('Text copied to clipboard!');
      } catch (err) {
        window.prompt("To copy the text to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", textToCopy);
      }
     $(".textToCopyInput").remove();
}
```

***PS:*** I am sorry if my note offended or angered you. After looking over it a second time, I realised that someone could take it the wrong way. I hope you understand.